# DFS configuration through powershell in AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, windows-server-2012, dfs-r

What my task is:

Trying to automate DFSR installation as well as configuration through powershell. I've two AWS test instances with AWS directory services running. So, obviously my domain is with AWS Directory Services, not any other like Windows AD.

What I have done so far:

Have installed AD tools and upgraded powershell to v4.0. I can install dfs through powershell (I tested), but while configuring it says I need to have ADWS running. Since this is not a dc, I have no such service.

What I need to know:
Is there any specific requirement that DFS through powershell requires ADWS services running? Or for AWS scenario, is there any other solution that I can depend on? or any other idea to make this work?

Any help would be really appreciated.

**Edit:**

I am able to configure DFSR through powershell, which means it is success on first part but fails with the error **Add-DfsrMember : Could not add the computer to the replication group. Computer: server.domain.net Replication group: "group" The network path was not found**. I have installed remote server admin tools for ADDS and ADLDS, but no luck. I can see the group created but not added any members.

Manually when I try to configure DFS, I am recieving the error shown below while adding a member. Any idea..?

[image]

Same case in both Windows 2012 as well as 2012 R2. The same setup has been done in some other environment with the same specs (domain is from AWS Directory services, no AD or DNS servers in that environment too, but there DFS works).

Comment: Questions that relate to unsupported hardware or software platforms may not be suitable for ServerFault

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Though AWS Directory Services is not a Windows AD, you can get this done. It was an issue with the port groups which were not opened.

Follow this [blog](https://systemadminguide.wordpress.com/2015/04/17/dfsr-configuration-using-powershell/) to get the powershell script.

Answer (score 1):

> So, obviously my domain is with AWS Directory Services, not any other like Windows AD.

Do not pass Go; do not collect $200.

DFSR requires Active Directory.

From [TechNet](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc773238(v=ws.10).aspx):

> Can I use DFS Replication in a workgroup?
>
> No. DFS Replication relies on Active Directory® Domain Services for
>   configuration. It will only work in a domain.

Comment: Yup - No AD, No AD features- game over.

Comment: @JimB and Ryan: But I have a domain, just that it's using AWS directory services. So, doesn't that can be considered in DFSR using powershell??

Comment: @serverstackqns Sorry, no, Amazon Directory Services is not Microsoft AD.  It has to be Microsoft AD. DFSR stores configuration information in a special location that is unique to Microsoft AD. Additionally, AD Web Services (ADWS) is something that will be running on all Microsoft AD domain controllers.  But it does not exist on AWS Directory Services. You also need that.

Comment: You have a directory service- you do not have an Active directory forest or an active directory domain. Their web pages mention it as "Active Directory compatible (Samba) directory" so I guess you have a Samba forest.  You can integrate an AD Forest to AWS Directories so you could go that route.

Comment: @JimB: But manually I could do, like create a replication group as well as I can do dfs replication between multiple servers. There also the same configuration exists. How come manually and not supported through powershell then?

Comment: @JimB and Ryan: See my edited part in question.